# How to keep track of the since_id parameter in my Processing + Twitter4j application?

Tags: processing, twitter4j

I am using the Twitter4j library in Processing to retrieve tweets.  I have added a timer to my application so that it collects tweets at appropriate intervals without hitting the Twitter API too many times.  However, I am having trouble implementing the Since_Id parameter in order to step forward (instead of backwards as I am now) through the timeline of tweets.  How do I keep track of the MAX_ID so that value is fed into the next interval when the timer tells my application to run again.

```
Timer timer;
import java.util.List;

void setup() {  
  timer = new Timer(30000);
  timer.start();
  goTwitter();
} 

void draw(){
   if (timer.isFinished()){
     goTwitter();
     timer.start();
   }
}

void goTwitter(){

  ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
  cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("");
  cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret("");
  cb.setOAuthAccessToken("");
  cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("");

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
  Query query = new Query("#processing");

  int numberOfTweets = 300;
  long lastID = Long.MAX_VALUE;

  ArrayList<Status> tweets = new ArrayList<Status>();
  while (tweets.size () < numberOfTweets) {
    if (numberOfTweets - tweets.size() > 100)
      query.setCount(100);
    else 
      query.setCount(numberOfTweets - tweets.size());
    try {
      QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
      tweets.addAll(result.getTweets());
      println("Gathered " + tweets.size() + " tweets");
      for (Status t: tweets) 
        if(t.getId() < lastID) lastID = t.getId();

    }

    catch (TwitterException te) {
      println("Couldn't connect: " + te);
    }; 
    query.setMaxId(lastID-1);       
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < tweets.size(); i++) {
    Status t = (Status) tweets.get(i);

    GeoLocation loc = t.getGeoLocation();

    String user = t.getUser().getScreenName();
    String msg = t.getText();
    String time = "";
    if (loc!=null) {
      Double lat = t.getGeoLocation().getLatitude();
      Double lon = t.getGeoLocation().getLongitude();
      println(i + " USER: " + user + " wrote: " + msg + " located at " + lat + ", " + lon);                     
    }     
  }
  println("lastID= " + lastID);
}

class Timer {
  int savedTime;
  int totalTime;

  Timer (int tempTotalTime) {
    totalTime = tempTotalTime;
  }

  void start(){
    savedTime = millis();
  }

 boolean isFinished() {
    int passedTime = millis() - savedTime;
    if (passedTime > totalTime){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take the line

```
long lastID = Long.MAX_VALUE;
```

and move it right above

```
void setup() {
```

like this:

```
long lastID = Long.MAX_VALUE;
void setup() {
```

essentially making it a variable that can be accessed by every method in your Processing sketch, a kind of "global variable". Also, if you want it to restart every time after it has reached the number of tweets you should to change the else clause in the while loop and make it like this

```
else {
 query.setCount(numberOfTweets - tweets.size());
 long lastID = Long.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, Petros!  One additional question: in order to step forward in the timeline and use the global variable you suggested, should I change the "query.setMaxID()" to "query.setSinceId()"? I would like my application to collect the newest tweets at set intervals in order to minimize the redundant results I get from searching backwards in the timeline.

Comment: I guess you could use it, and I can see the benefits, but you have to think of your loops a little differently... There are also some questions for you to think about. Like what happens if you don't update for a long time and there are a lot of tweets. Do you want all the tweets up until the point you last updated or do you just want the last 300, no matter what lies in between? Are you going to store the tweets and only retrieve the new ones when they are created, or do you want to always want to pull the new ones, as well as the ones you already have up to a number?

Comment: Actually why don't you split the question into another one?